# Javascript Speech Recognition API not continuous on mobile device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, voice-recognition, continuous

So I have been developing an app on react and it uses voice recognition, I have set it up and works fine on PC but when I try it on my phone it runs and works but it stops after transcription.

I have enabled `recognition.continuous = true;`

Code to invoke speech recognition.

```
    voiceCommands() {
        recognition.onstart = () => {
            console.log('Voice is activated');
        }

        recognition.onresult = (e) => {
            const current = e.resultIndex;
            let transcript = e.results[current][0].transcript;
            let mobileRepeatBug = (current == 1 && transcript == e.results[0][0].transcript);

            if(!mobileRepeatBug) {
                if(transcript === 'next' || transcript === ' next') {
                    this.incrementStep();
                    e.reuslts = {};
                }

                if(transcript === 'back' || transcript === ' back') {
                    this.decrementStep();
                    e.reuslts = {};
                }
            }

        }

        recognition.onspeechend = () => {
            recognition.stop();
            console.log('voice stopped');
        }
    }
```

Code for the button that changes the state

```
    handleVoice() {
        this.setState({
            voice: !this.state.voice
        }, () => {
            if(this.state.voice) {
                recognition.start();
                console.log("Voice started");
            } else {
                recognition.stop();
            }
        });

    }
```

My aim is to make it run continuously until I disable it with the button. Im not sure if this is something to do with how chrome deals with voice permissions on the phone and if this is even possible.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: just start() it again after it ends.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have tried that but it just gives me and error saying that its already been started. (even though i have stopped it in the code)

Comment: put that in a setTimeout or interval and you can use try catch

Comment: Could you please give me an example

Comment: also your code has a typo `reuslts`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start again after an interval.

```js
recognition.onresult = (e) => {
            const current = e.resultIndex;
            let transcript = e.results[current][0].transcript;
            let mobileRepeatBug = (current == 1 && transcript == e.results[0][0].transcript);

            if(!mobileRepeatBug) {
                if(transcript === 'next' || transcript === ' next') {
                    this.incrementStep();
                    e.results = {};
                }

                if(transcript === 'back' || transcript === ' back') {
                    this.decrementStep();
                    e.results = {};
                }
            }
          setTimeout(() => {
            recognition.start();
          }, 50);

        }
```

Comment: You can conditionally set the timeout based in case you want to stop the recording

Comment: no im just lucky i used speech recognition api before haha

Comment: Thanks mate, you made my day, been trying to figuring this out all day